# What financial return do investors get when they buy shares in a company besides dividends, value of assets, and gains from changes in stock price?

Tags: stocks, shares, equity

I'm confused why a shareholder would purchase shares in a stock that doesn't pay dividends.

- *They don't get part of the profits:* Without dividends, when the company earns profits, the shareholder doesn't get any of that money directly.
- *They don't want to liquidate the assets:* They own a share of the assets less liabilities, but presumably in most cases, unless they are dealing in bankrupt businesses, they don't buy a company with the intention of liquidating its assets.
- *They don't want to sell the business:* They might value the assets as a way to sell the business to another business. But again, for instance, Amazon is not selling its business to another business. And yet people still want to buy shares of Amazon. So presumably an investor doesn't count on selling the business as their main form of return.

This seems to indicate if (1) the business does well, (2) continues to not pay a dividend, (3) and doesn't sell its business, then no direct payments of any kind will come to the investor.

This seems to reduce the financial value of owning shares down to strictly their trade value.
It seems to me owning the business is then rather like owning trading cards. When you buy trading cards, you don't get money until you sell the card. Similarly, if you buy a stock under the above conditions, then you also don't get any money until you sell it. It would seem then, the primary value of the shares is other people want them and, the more people want them, the more valuable they get.

Am I missing something? What financial return do investors get when they buy shares in a company besides dividends, value of assets, and gains from changes in stock price? Is buying and selling the stock the main financial gain an investor gets from purchasing shares?

I'm excluding things like wanting "control" of the company as I can't see what financial value that brings other than influencing the decisions above.

Comment: Note that even dividends do not provide "return". They reduce the value of the company proportionally, so a $100 stock that pays a $5 dividend will be worth $95 after the dividend. They provide _cash flow_ but not _return_.

Comment: They get a share of the assets when the company is liquidated in the future. If the stock price was less than the assets, someone could get a huge loan, buy all of Amazon, liquidate it, and pay back the loan and have some profit.

Comment: @DStanley great point. i mixed that up. thanks for clarifying

Comment: But, it doesn't answer your question - does the duplicate answer your question? If not, what part of your question does it not answer?

Comment: @DStanley I think many of the answers in the duplicate did not answer the question and that made me confused what the answer was. 2/21 of those did seem to answer the question, so I just wanted to confirm really. I think I would have been more certain if more of the answers had actually answered the question in that particular thread. It would be nice if there were a community wiki that sort of summarized some of the points that did answer the question.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, the value is ultimately the prospect of liquidation somehow. The current worth is what someone _else_ would pay for that future possibility. There is no way to extract the actual stock value from the company yourself. Whether you _like_ that answer or not is another matter...

Comment: @DStanley Perfect! thanks so much for following up and answering my question. Perhaps next time I will just do this in a comment instead for questions like this. I'm not sure reasking was the best strategy since you answered it in a comment in the end quite easily. In any case, appreciate it! Have a nice day/evening!